# What is difference between /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i and /usr/sbin/sendmail in server configuration?

Tags: php, joomla

I have upload my joomla project on live server (Linux basd LAMP) in phpinfo file I found the `"/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"` for smtp configuration. and  my local WAMP server configuration use `"/usr/sbin/sendmail"` any please let know why use `-t` and `-i`.  what is it ?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to discern this with [`man sendmail`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sendmail/). The `-i` option prevent a single line containing `.` from being treated as a message terminator (on the off chance that a valid message may contain a line like that) while `-t` means that it will get the recipient list from the message headers (`to:`, `cc:` and `bcc:`) as well as the command line (which may well be empty so you probably *want* to scan the headers).